# Update trigger not updating timestamp(update operation) in column

Tags: sql, oracle

Trigger not working while updating the table column with trigger enabled on table...

```
      CREATE OR REPLACE Trigger TR_FinlStatAssetDesignation_U
    BEFORE Update
    on FINLSTATASSETDESIGNATION FOR EACH ROW
       DECLARE
       v_AtDateTime  TIMESTAMP(3);
       v_LogOperation  NUMBER(3,0);
       v_UserName  VARCHAR2(255);
       v_AppName  VARCHAR2(255);
       SWV_error NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 0;
    BEGIN

       begin
          select   USERNAME INTO v_UserName FROM v$session  WHERE (audsid = SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','sessionid')) AND ROWNUM <=1;
          EXCEPTION
          WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
             NULL;
       end;

       SELECT program INTO v_AppName FROM v$session WHERE audsid=userenv('sessionid'); 
       if (LENGTH(v_AppName) = 0) then 
          v_AppName := 'Unknown';
       end if; 

       SELECT distinct TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'DD-MON-YY hh24:mi:SS.FF AM') INTO v_AtDateTime FROM dual;


       if UPDATING('FinlStatAssetDesignation') then
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Invalid attempt to update OID FinlStatAssetDesignation in FinlStatAssetDesignation');
          /*    
    ROLLBACK */
    return;
       end if;

       if not UPDATING('UpdDate') then
          SWV_error := 0;
          begin
             UPDATE FinlStatAssetDesignation a SET(UpdDate) =(SELECT distinct v_AtDateTime FROM dual where a.FinlStatAssetDesignation = :NEW.FinlStatAssetDesignation)
             WHERE ROWID IN(SELECT a.ROWID FROM FinlStatAssetDesignation a where a.FinlStatAssetDesignation = :NEW.FinlStatAssetDesignation);
             EXCEPTION
             WHEN OTHERS THEN
                SWV_error := SQLCODE;
          end;
          if SWV_error <> 0 then
             /* 
    ROLLBACK */
    return;
          end if;
       end if;
       END;

        QL>  select * from finlstatassetdesignation;

FINLSTATAS FINLSTATASSETDESIGNATIONDESC                       UPDOPERATION
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------
UPDDATE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
one19      anything                                                      0
01-JAN-17 08.00.00.000000 AM

SQL>  update finlstatassetdesignation set finlstatassetdesignationdesc ='nothing';

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from finlstatassetdesignation;

FINLSTATAS FINLSTATASSETDESIGNATIONDESC                       UPDOPERATION
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------
UPDDATE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
one19      nothing                                                       0
01-JAN-17 08.00.00.000000 AM


    SQL> desc finlstatassetdesignation;
     Name                                      Null?    Type
     ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
     FINLSTATASSETDESIGNATION                  NOT NULL CHAR(10 CHAR)
     FINLSTATASSETDESIGNATIONDESC              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
     UPDOPERATION                              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
     UPDDATE                                   NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)
```

Trying to update column FINLSTATASSETDESIGNATIONDESC gets succeded however doesnt update the timestamp in column UPDDATE

Please help....in fixing this trigger...

Trigger not working while updating the table column with trigger enabled on table...

Comment: You are fetching a string (`TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, …)`) into a timestamp variable `v_AtDateTime`. Also, what is the type of `UpdDate` column?

Comment: @Aleksej, it is a `TIMESTAMP` as given in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is a bad idea to write strings (i.e. `TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:SS.FF AM') INTO v_AtDateTime`) when you actually want to write timestamps.

There are several weak points in your code, according to my understanding you can write it simpler:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_FinlStatAssetDesignation_U
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON FINLSTATASSETDESIGNATION FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

   IF UPDATING('FinlStatAssetDesignation') THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Invalid attempt to update OID FinlStatAssetDesignation in FinlStatAssetDesignation');
      -- Rather strange if a column has the same name as the table
   END IF;

   IF NOT UPDATING('UpdDate') THEN
     :NEW.UpdDate := SYSTIMESTAMP;
   END IF;
END;
```

Everything else in your code is redundant, resp. junk.

In case you need the username somewhere, just write `USER` instead of

```
select   USERNAME INTO v_UserName 
FROM v$session  
WHERE (audsid = SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','sessionid')) AND ROWNUM <=1;
```

For application use `NVL(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CLIENT_PROGRAM_NAME'), 'Unknown')` instead of

```
  SELECT program INTO v_AppName FROM v$session WHERE audsid=userenv('sessionid'); 
   if (LENGTH(v_AppName) = 0) then 
      v_AppName := 'Unknown';
   end if;
```

Comment: @Wernfried...Thanks that worked like a charm...I have modified it a bit more for my use case..